# Building a Markov model from a text file?

Tags: python

I have an assignment to build a program that, based off an input file, reads text and then generates new text. The dictionary should map n string of letters to a list of letters that could follow the string, based off the text in the input file. Thus far, I have

```
def create_dic():
    n = order_entry.get()
    inputfile = file_entry.get() #name of input file
    lines = open(inputfile,'r').read() #reads input file into string
    model = {} #empty dictionary to build Markov model
```

For every n-character sequence in the input, I have to "look it up in the dictionary to get a list of possible succeeding characters and get the next character." I'm confused about instruction to look up the string in the dictionary when the dictionary is empty to begin with? Won't there be nothing in the dictionary?

Comment: That's probably your job: Populate the dictionary.

Comment: The book [The Practice of Programming](http://www.informit.com/store/practice-of-programming-9780201615869) has a chapter about implementing a program rather like this.  The difference there is that it works with words rather than characters, but otherwise, the job is remarkably similar.  (AFAICT, the web site at Bell Labs -- http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/tpop/ -- has gone AWOL at some time since 2015-04-04.)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an assignment, I will give you leading questions rather than an answer. As @Quirliom said, "Populate the dictionary."

When you want to use the Markov model, what key would you like to search the dictionary for?

When you search for that key, what would you like to get back?

The sentence, "The dictionary should map n string of letters to a list of letters that could follow the string, based off the text in the input file," has the answers to those questions. This means that you will have to do some work on the input file to figure out how to extract the dictionary keys and what they should map to.

Comment: When you use the Markov model, you would be searching for the n-character string and the value would be a list of possible succeeding letters, correct? The instructions after that as follows: "Get the next character following the sequence from the input, add that character to the list of successors, and put the list back into the dictionary." So it would appear that's how you populate the dictionary. I'm having trouble understanding how you get any lists at all. For n=1, when you look up the dictionary, it is empty so there is no list of possible successors. So the dictionary remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

this is definitely not the best approach, but you  start with this.

- on letter basis: which letter is in the first place most (for entire data).

first character (letter) of the words are countable entities. and it is rational to check which character (letter) has most records. start your generated text with this. then look which letter most succeeds this and so on. also take average word length and distribute generated words around this length.

for better results:

- on n gram basis: which n-gram is most likely to precede others (you can extend it also as sentences)